# How backspace can actually delete the string in getchar() loop

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#define ENTER_KEY '\n'
#define NULL_TERMINATOR '\0'

int main()
{
    char name[100], input;
    int counter = 0;
    while(input != ENTER_KEY)
    {
        input = getchar();
        name[counter] = input;
        counter++;
    }
    counter--;
    name[counter] = NULL_TERMINATOR;
    printf("%s", name);
    return 0;
}
```

If I write something, it should continuously saved in the *name* Array. And the *counter* should go up on every character I enter. But if I press Backspace, it looks like it makes the counter decreased. Because for example if I write "abcdef" and press backspace 3 times and change that to "abcxyz", and then press Enter. It prints "abcxyz".

Comment: `printf` prints `abcdef\b\b\bxyz` which prints as `abcxyz` on the console. Try to write to a file, you'll see the difference

Comment: you were right to de-accept my answer. But you can accept Serge's

Comment: I am new here, i don't know how this work. I did not even want to do that.

Comment: you did OK, don't worry

Comment: For modern Unix/Linux terminals you have to turn off canonical input mode( see manual for tcsetattr). Otherwise input using getchar is buffered. Maybe you need to turn off echoing input also. Then just decrement your index variable if it is not equal to 0 when you face '\b'.

Comment: I don't know how to handle terminal in win but handle '\b' is easy. But if you have do output in parallel and you have '\t'...

Comment: Aside: use `int input` and not `char input`.  `int getchar()` typically returns 257 different values: the negative `EOF` and `[0...255]`.  Saving to a `char` can lose information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on the console *driver*. On most systems (at least Unix-like in line mode and in Windows console), the program does not receive the characters at the moment they are typed but the system prepares a line (up to the newline character) and sends the full line to the program.

In that case, the backspace if often used to edit that *console buffer*, meaning that the characters erased are actually removed before being handed to the program. So if you type `abcdef<backspace><backspace><backspace>xyz<Return>` the program will receive the following string: `"abcxyz\n"`.

Beware, in a GUI program or in fullscreen text mode program like emacs or vi, the system is in raw mode (Unix language) and each character is received when it is typed. In that case, the program has to manage the input and erase its own character array when it receives a `<backspace>`.